# Как правильно выполнять connect() для List?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть лист объектов, а конкретно `QTextEdit()`. QDynamicListEdit просто child с некоторыми дополнительными переменными

```
QList<QDynamicLineEdit*> listLineEdit;
```

Лист пополняется объектами по нажатию кнопки, т.е добавляется еще один `QTextEdit`.

```
void MainWindow::addTranslateButtonHandler()
{
   QDynamicLineEdit *newLineEdit = new QDynamicLineEdit();
   listLineEdit.append(newLineEdit);
   translateLayout ->addRow("Translate "+QString::number(newLineEdit->getId()),newLineEdit);
}
```

Есть событие, которое должен обрабатывать каждый элемент списка

```
void MainWindow::textChangedTextEditHandler(){
    QSize size = exampleTextEdit->document()->size().toSize();
    exampleTextEdit->setFixedHeight(size.height() + 3);
}
```

Как правильно и красиво сделать `connect()` ко всем объектам в List?

Comment: сдесь тольк два варианта: for или for_each - да и те, по сути, одинаковы

Comment: дык а в самом `addTranslateButtonHandler` почему сразу `connect` не выполнить, чтобы потом for не использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В любом случае придётся коннектится к каждому элементу списка. Проще всего это сделать прямо при создании. Список в принципе не нужен.

Чтобы определять, от какого именно виджета пришёл сигнал можно использовать или соединение с лямбдой:

```
void MainWindow::addTranslateButtonHandler() {
   QDynamicLineEdit *newLineEdit = new QDynamicLineEdit();
   // ...
   connect(newLineEdit, &QTextEdit::textChanged, [newLineEdit](){
         QSize size = newLineEdit->document()->size().toSize();
         newLineEdit->setFixedHeight(size.height() + 3);
   });
}
```

или `sender()` в обычном слоте:

```
void MainWindow::textChangedTextEditHandler(){
    QTextEdit *exampleTextEdit = qobject_cast<QTextEdit*>(sender());
    assert(exampleTextEdit);
    QSize size = exampleTextEdit->document()->size().toSize();
    exampleTextEdit->setFixedHeight(size.height() + 3);
}
```